# Need help in Latching ON/OFF switch

Tags: microcontroller, power, low-power, latch, latching

I am working on a latching on/off switch, There are many ways to do it by using discrete components. But I want to use an IC to perform that task. I found **MAX16054** IC which is similar to my application but the drawback with that, working voltage is 2.7V min. While I am working with minimum of 2.1V.
Is there any better way to find the solution for this, I don't want to use 555 timer IC.

Please check the circuit
[image]

Comment: The 555 would have a minimum of 5V for supply, so you can already rule it out. LTC2955 and 2956 are rated at 1.5V; or you can go all out and use a micropower microcontroller like the MSP430, they start at 1.8V and there are special models going ever lower. The MSP430L092 works with even 0.9V

Comment: Does your processor have an ultra-low power mode? If so, the processor itself could do this, by waking up when the button is pressed.

Comment: LDO with low quiscient current and using sleep mode of MCU will do the task.

Comment: @LorenzoMarcantonio  LTC2955 and 2956 will suitable for me but they are too costly do you know any other IC with lesser price.

Comment: The most entry level MSP430 is 25 cent (in quantity). Otherwise go discrete

Comment: Holtek HT7121-1 2.1V 30mA regulator is 4uA Iq maximum. Or run the uC off the battery directly, if possible.

Comment: I find this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7D9L9oS4AJM&t=1002s) to be a great source of inspiration. You would have to choose the right mosfets to get your desired operating range.

Comment: @Fiebbo I have seen that video and I don't want to use any controller GPIO. Latching has to be independent and i don't want discrete components circuit also. I want a separate IC which takes care of latching.

Comment: @LorenzoMarcantonio What is MSP430 IC. I am not able to find the application of latching.  I was getting texas flash IC's with that MPN. Can you please tell me the whole part number.

Comment: Exactly. You take an extremely cheap MCU and program it to do your biddings. At these price point often is convenient